# ParseError parsing empty valued xml doc

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are lots of articles pertaining to parsing xml with elementtree. I've gone through a bunch of them and read through the docs but I can't come up with a solution that works for me. I'm trying to supplement info thats created by another app in a nfo file but i need to preserve the conventions in the file.

Here is an example of how the file is laid out

```
<title>
  <name>Test Name</name>
  <alt name />
  <file local="C:\file\file1.doc" type="word">http://filestore/file1.doc</file>
  <file local="" type="excel">http://filestore/file2.xls</file>
  <file local="C:\file\file3.xls" type="excel" />
  <file local="" type="ppt" />
</title>
```

Note: Elements are not closed properly e.g...

```
<alt name /> should be <alt name></alt name>
```

This is what I'm running...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.nfo')
root = tree.getroot()
```

The error I'm getting is...

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token):

I've tried...

```
myparser = ET.XMLParser(encoding='UTF-8')
tree = ET.parse('file.nfo', myparser)
```

Also tried, xmlparser, opening with codecs but i'm pretty sure its the formatting. I'm guessing the immediate issue is non-escaped > but i suspect ET needs opening/closing?

I'm sure i could open this file and go through it with regex but i was hoping to use ElementTree.

The end goal is to have the details from the nfo as a dictionary that looks like...

```
dict = {'title': [{'name': 'Test Name',
    'alt name': '',
    'file': [{'local': 'C:\file\file1.doc', 'type': 'word', 'url': 'http://filestore/file1.doc'},
        {'local': '', 'type': 'excel', 'url': 'http://filestore/file2.xls'},
        {'local': 'C:\file\file3.xls', 'type': 'excel', 'url': ''},
        {'local': '', 'type': 'ppt', 'url': ''}]
    }]}
```

I'm sure there is a better (more pythonic) way to do this but I'm pretty new to python.

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: I'm also trying to avoid using 3rd party libraries if possible

Comment: The error message is not surprising since the sample document is not well-formed. The problem is the `<alt name />` bit. An XML element simply cannot look like that. If it is changed to `<alt name="xyz"/>` (for example), your code would work.

Comment: Note that changing from `<alt name />` to `<alt name></alt name>` would not help. It would still be ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, problem is i need to maintain the poor formatting so that the existing app that creates/uses it continues to work. Using <alt name></alt name> works flawlessly (with or without value) in my tests.

Comment: The "poor formatting" means that the document is not XML. That in turn means that you cannot expect to process it with XML tools. And I don't know what tests you do, but `<alt name></alt name>` is still bad.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i **don't** disagree with you and i don't know enough about it to comment further. My hands are kind of tied is usage though. What i can say however is that the ElementTree.write() method formats it this way

Comment: I thought that the problem was about **parsing** XML. There is nothing about **writing** (using `ElementTree.write()`) in the question. Sorry, but I'm not sure what else I can say. It is too bad that your hands are tied.

Comment: Btw, what exactly is "info thats created by another app in a nfo file"?

Comment: I'm also re-writing the nfo file with additional information that i'm gleaning from outside of the app, that part i'm not having a problem with. So i didn't include it in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up creating a customer parser of sorts, its not ideal but it works. It was suggested to me that lxml and html.parser may parse malformed xml better but i just went with this.

I'm also still very interested in any feedback whether it be on this or using any other method.

```
import re

def merge_dicts(*dict_args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in dict_args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result

def make_dict(str_arg, op):
    result = {}
    result = dict(s.split(op) for s in str_arg.split(","))
    return result

'''
Samples
lst = r'  <name>Test Name</name>'
lst = r'  <alt name />'
lst = r'  <file local="C:\file\file1.doc" type="word">http://filestore/file1.doc</file>'
lst = r'  <file local="" type="excel">http://filestore/file2.xls</file>'
lst = r'  <file local="C:\file\file3.xls" type="excel" />'
lst = r'  <file local="" type="ppt" />'
'''
def match_pattern(file_str):
    #<description>desc blah</description>'
    pattern1 = r'''(?x)
    ^
    \s*                                             # cut leading whitespace
    (?P<whole_thing>
        < (?P<tag_open> (\w+?|\w*\s\w+?)+) \b       # word boundary, so we can
        >                                           # skip attributes
        (?P<tag_body> .+? )                         # insides
        </ (?P<tag_close> (\w+?|\w*\s\w+?)+) >      # closing tag, nothing interesting
    )
    $'''

    #<alt name />
    pattern2 = r'''(?x)
    ^
    \s*
    (?P<whole_thing>
        < (?P<tag_open> (\w+?|\w*\s\w+?)+) \b
        \s/>
    )
    $'''

    #<file local="C:\file\file1.doc" type="word">http://filestore/file1.doc</file>'
    pattern3 = r'''(?x)
        ^
        \s*
        (?P<whole_thing>
            < (?P<tag_open> (\w+?|\w*\s\w+!=?)+) \b
            \s
            (?P<tag_attrib1> (\w*\=.*?))            # 1st attribute
            \s
            (?P<tag_attrib2> (\w*\=.*))             # 2nd attribute
            .*? >
            (?P<tag_body> .+? )
            </ (?P<tag_close> (\w+?|\w*\s\w+?)+) >
        )
        $'''

    #<file local="" type="ppt" />
    pattern4 = r'''(?x)
        ^
        \s*
        (?P<whole_thing>
            < (?P<tag_open> (\w+?|\w*\s\w+!=?)+) \b
            \s
            (?P<tag_attrib1> (\w*\=.*?))            # 1st attribute
            \s
            (?P<tag_attrib2> (\w*\=.*))             # 2nd attribute
            \s/>
        )
        $'''

    pat_str = 'pattern'
    pat_val = 1
    return_dict = {}
    while (pat_val <= 4):
        pattern = pat_str+str(pat_val)
        matchObj = re.match(eval(pattern), file_str, re.L|re.M)

        if matchObj:
            #for k, v in matchObj.groupdict().items():
            #    print('matchObj.group({!r}) == {!r}'.format(k, v))
            if pat_val == 1:
                body = matchObj.group('tag_body')
                return_dict = {matchObj.group('tag_open'): body}
            elif pat_val == 2:
                return_dict = {matchObj.group('tag_open'): ''}
            elif pat_val == 3:
                attr1 = make_dict(matchObj.group('tag_attrib1'), '=')
                attr2 = make_dict(matchObj.group('tag_attrib2'), '=')
                body = {'url': matchObj.group('tag_body')}
                attrib = merge_dicts(attr1, attr2, body)
                return_dict = {matchObj.group('tag_open'): attrib}
            elif pat_val == 4:
                attr1 = make_dict(matchObj.group('tag_attrib1'), '=')
                attr2 = make_dict(matchObj.group('tag_attrib2'), '=')
                body = {'url': ''}
                attrib = merge_dicts(attr1, attr2, body)
                return_dict = {matchObj.group('tag_open'): attrib}
            return return_dict
        else:
            pat_val = pat_val + 1
            if pat_val > 4:
                print("No match!!")  

#print(match_pattern(lst))

def in_file(file):
    result = {}
    with open(file, "r") as file:
        data = (file.read().splitlines())
        for d in data:
            if data.index(d) == 0 or data.index(d) == len(data)-1:
                if data.index(d) == 0:
                    print(re.sub('<|/|>', '', d))
            elif d:
                lst = []
                dct = {}
                if 'file' in match_pattern(d).keys():
                    for i in match_pattern(d).items():
                        if 'file' in result.keys():
                            lst = result['file']
                            lst.append(i[1])
                            dct = {i[0]: lst}
                            result = merge_dicts(result, dct)
                            #print(result['file'])
                        else:
                            dct = {i[0]: [i[1]]}
                            result = merge_dicts(result, dct)
                else:
                    result = merge_dicts(result, match_pattern(d))
                    print('else', match_pattern(d))
    return result

print(in_file('C:\\test.nfo'))
```

NOTE: I dropped the top most dictionary from the original post